# Oracle SQL -- insert multiple rows into a table with one statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I'd like to do insert N rows that are all identical, except one of the values is different. Specifically, this is what I am trying:

```
insert into attribute_list (id,value,name)
values 
(
select (id,'Y','is_leveled') from value_list where val >= 50
);
```

So for every value that has a val >= 50, I would insert one row into attribute_list. Can this be done with one insert statement or should I just manually generate these inserts in excel?

(note: this is a cooked example simplified to clarify the issue, so no need to attack the needlessness of this specific case)

Comment: So, if multiple rows in value_list for the same id have val >= 50, do you want run row for that id in attribute_list?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Cool question. I assume if I only wanted it to once I'd just select unique ids with a sub-select.

Comment: Or `select distinct id, 'Y', 'is_leveled' from ....`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can absolutely do this in a single statement!

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO attribute_list (id, value, name)
SELECT id, 'Y', 'is_leveled'
FROM value_list WHERE val >= 50
```

Answer (score 5):

That is what [FOR loops](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm) are for.

```
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN     -- i is even
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I think this missed the point of the question. It inserts multiple values, but not with a single statement.

Comment: I consider these one line inserts convenient shorthands for the real thing: the loop. As soon as things get only mildly interesting, you have to loop anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need an INSERT from SELECT. To do so you should omit the `VALUES` and just do:

```
insert into attribute_list (id,value,name)
select (id,'Y','is_leveled') from value_list where val >= 50;
```

Here's an example: http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `SELECT ... INTO` if you can query the data. Otherwise to create data you'd need to use PL/SQL

If you have the data then try:

```
select id,'Y','is_leveled'
INTO attribute_list 
from value_list where val >= 50
```